# Docker: Could not read CA certificate: no such file or directory

Tags: macos, docker, certificate

I'm on OSX and I've used docker-machine before, but now that there is a native [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) I wanted to install that.
So I uninstalled docker-machine using [this uninstall script](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/uninstall.sh), and then I installed and started Docker for Mac without a problem.

I can run `docker --help`, which shows me all options as expected.

When I run `docker ps` however, I get the following:

> $ docker ps
>   Could not read CA certificate "/Users/kramer65/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem": open /Users/kramer65/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem: no such file or directory

I tried the solution from [this answer](https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/issues/126#issuecomment-131553389) (including sourcing the `.bash_profile` to activate it), but that didn't solve anything.

Does anybody know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: What do you see when you run `docker version`? It sounds from the error message your docker agent still tries to communicate with the docker machine.

Comment: @YaronIdan - I get the same error :'(  But when I run `which docker` I get `/usr/local/bin/docker` which is a symlink to `/Users/kramer65/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/bin/docker` which in turn is a symlink to `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please remove your old docker-machine

```
docker-machine rm default
```

then, edit your .bashrc .profile or .zshrc (whatever you use) and remove anything that exports DOCKER env variables (like socket, host, port and so on).

Restart your shell at least, you can restart your Mac. When you do

```
env | grep DOCKER
```

You should see nothing. `docker ps` should now work flawlessly.

Background:
The problem is that the old `dockertoolbox` defines a custom host/port and puts that into your bashrc and does not remove it after uninstallation.

docker for mac uses the Unix default socket, but it will not get picked up until you remove those old ENV variables

Answer (score 0):

Run these command in PowerShell and re-open: 
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_CERT_PATH", $null, "User") [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_HOST", $null, "User") [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME", $null, "User") [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY", $null, "User") [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH", $null, "User")

Comment: This is not answering the OP's question, but yes, it also solves the problem under windows. You can also just delete the environment variables in the control panel.